# Bypass motherboard with USB Header to External USB Adapter

Tags: usb

I have a Cosair cooling kit that is Cosair link enabled running in a case with a bunch of fans and a PSU and storage in a jerry rigged DAS setup... no motherboard. The Cosair link system requires a USB header on the motherboard to plug itself into, not for power but for software control.

So I want to get an adapter that basically takes the connector from the Cosair link system and converts into a regular 2.0 USB connector and plug that into my laptop so i can use the software to control the fans. i.e. bypass the motherboard that would normally be in the case with fans and storage.

I looked at the header expander from NZTX but that expands a motherboard USB header, it does not  adapt a female USB connector coming out of a device (like Cosair Link Commander) to a regular USB connector.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this do?

[image]

Amazon [has it listed](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000V6WD8A) as a Adapter Cable, USB 2.0, IDC 5 Male (single row) to USB A Male

Comment: Perfect. I guess I should have been able to find that myself but for whatever reason didn't. tyvm

Comment: google fu -  While it wasn't my initial search "5 pin header USB male" works perfectly. Just to note you can find it cheaper elsewhere, but amazon was the place I found first (and Stackexchange gets money off referrals ;p)